# Javascript: Building table and inserting Data

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to build a table completely from Javascript and without using HTML?  I have some code here that's pretty self explanatory and want to create a HTML table by using Javascript.

What I did was separated the rows starting with the header and initializd a variable "container" that contains "tableContainer" but no idea how to implement the javascript portion when it comes to creating the table.

```
function jsonTable() {
    var data = {
        headers: ["First Name", "Last Name", "Age"],
        rows: [
            ["John", "Doe", 30],
            ["Jane", "Doe", 27],
            ["Mac", "Smith", 52]
        ]
    };
    var container = document.getElementById("tableContainer");

}
```

Comment: Do you want to add it to your existing html file?

Comment: Yes, what I have now is just basic HTML with a div id called tableContainer

Comment: Do you want to add in your tablebody these rows?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, using `var table=document.createElement("table")` and append it to body using `document.body.append(table);` , then create tr and td same way as you created your table via `var tr=`document.createElement("tr") then append it to table using `table.append(tr);`.

here read about document.createElement() docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

and some sort of article or tutorial how to dynamically create table using js: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/04/generate-html-table-using-javascript.html

if you want the table to be appended to tableContainer div, then instead of appending it to body use `document.getElementById("tableContainer").append(table);`

**Please learn about basic js DOM manipulation**, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

and some tutorial/article: http://callmenick.com/post/basics-javascript-dom-manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. I used this (l[ink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) as a guide to write it.It could be a lot cleaner, but I really din't have a lot time in my hands now:

```
var dataSource = jsonTable();


function tableCreate() {
var container = document.getElementById("tableContainer");
var tbl = document.createElement("table");
var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
var header = document.createElement("THEAD");
tbl.appendChild(header);
tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
tbl.style.width = '50%';
tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';

var oRow = document.createElement("TR");
header.appendChild(oRow);
header.setAttribute("bgColor", "lightskyblue");
// Create and insert cells into the header row.
for (i = 0; i < dataSource.headers.length; i++) {
    var oCell = document.createElement("TH");
    oCell.innerHTML = dataSource.headers[i];
    oCell.style.border = '1px solid lightskyblue';
    oRow.appendChild(oCell);


}


// Insert rows and cells into bodies.
for (i = 0; i < dataSource.headers.length; i++) {

    oRow = document.createElement("TR");
    tblBody.appendChild(oRow);
    for (j = 0; j < dataSource.rows.length; j++) {
        oCell = document.createElement("TD");
        oCell.innerHTML = dataSource.rows[i][j];
        oCell.style.border = '1px solid black';
        oRow.appendChild(oCell);
    }
}

container.appendChild(tbl);




}

tableCreate();

function jsonTable() {
var data = {
    headers: ["First Name", "Last Name", "Age"],
    rows: [
        ["John", "Doe", 30],
        ["Jane", "Doe", 27],
        ["Mac", "Smith", 52]
    ]
};

return data;

}
```

I hope it helps.